# Quadrilateral Meshing Library

Tags: mesh

I am trying to find a meshing library written in C# to mesh custom shapes using quadrilateral meshes only.

Here is an example of the algorithm/Code I’m looking for. But this isn’t free and written in ANSI C. 
http://members.ozemail.com.au/~comecau/quad_build.htm

Comment: did you see this page about quad mesh rendering":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931626/how-do-i-convert-a-2d-mesh-of-triangles-into-quadrilaterals