# How do I convert a 2D mesh of triangles into quadrilaterals?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry

How do I convert a 2D mesh of triangles into quadrilaterals? Is this the best approach or it is even possible to generate a 2D quadrilateral mesh from scratch?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you want a mesh of a lower density than the original? Or does that not matter?

Comment: Okay. Otherwise my point would have been to perform one Catmull-Clark iteration.

Comment: @Bart: Actually, in 2d the problem is pretty easy, just throw the triangles away and keep the boundary, then apply Catmull-Clark to the boundary as if it were a single polygon. It's only slightly harder if there are holes.  The paper I link to in my answer is an elegant solution in the harder 3d case.

Comment: @DeepYellow +1 Hmm, true. Should have thought of that. For the 3D case there is also an excellent method by Cignoni I recall. I have to look it up though. Don't recall the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of their paper on Quad Mesh Simplification, Tarini et al. present a section on Tri to Quad mesh conversion (Section 6 to be precise).
You can find the paper [on the author's website](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/Publications/2010/TPCPP10/) here: ["Practical quad mesh simpliﬁcation" (PDF)](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/Publications/2010/TPCPP10/Tarini%20Pietroni%20Cignoni%20Panozzo%20Puppo%20-%20Practical%20Quad%20Semplification%20-%20EG%202010.pdf).

This has been published at:
Computer Graphics Forum (Special Issue of Eurographics 2010 Conference), Volume 29, Number 2, page 407-418 - 2010
DOI: [10.1111/j.1467-8659.2009.01610.x](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-8659.2009.01610.x/abstract)

The Open Source implementation should be available as part of [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard problem!  The approach that I like is given in this excellent paper:

[A Wave-based Anisotropic Quadrangulation Method](http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/zhangmuyang/projects/quadmesh_2010/Huang10WaveQuad.pdf)

Muyang Zhang, Jin Huang, Xinguo Liu and Hujun Bao.

ACM SIGGRAPH 2010

ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG) , 2010